# Finding the equation of a hyperbola, knowing the equations of its asymptotes and a point on it

Tags: analytic-geometry

Find the equation of the hyperbola, given that transverse axis parallel to the $x$-axis, equations of asymptotes are $4x + y - 7 = 0$ and $3x - y - 5 = 0$ and the hyperbola passes through point $(4,4)$.

How could I solve this problem?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Could you please show your efforts?

Comment: believe me I tried hard to solve this problem but I failed

Comment: @AnasYasser: Even when you don't know how to solve a problem, you can provide useful context. For instance, if this is a textbook exercise, what topic(s) and/or results were covered in the chapter? If this is a contest problem or online challenge, what's the target audience, and what level of sophistication is expected from the solution? ... The more you can say about the problem —showing that you're *engaged* in finding its solution— the better; simply posting an isolated problem statement tends to give the impression that you're just looking for someone to do your homework for you.

Comment: ok I got your point of view and I appreciate it

Comment: Let me prove my good intentions , I know that the general equation of the hyperbola is x^2/a^2 -y^2/b^2 when the transverse axis is parallel to the x-axis ,and when the center of the hyperbola is the origin,from solving the two equations we can get the center point of the hyperbola ,and from their slope we can get the values of a&b hence the equation is formed , my proplem here is that when I substitute with point given in the question ,it doesn`t achieve the equation, so that I restored to share it on this site

Answer (score 2):

$(4x+y-7)(3x-y-5)=k,$ and it passes through $(4,4)$: $(4\cdot 4+4-7)(3\cdot 4-4-5)=k$ or $k=39,$ so your equation is $$(4x+y-7)(3x-y-5)=39.$$

**Edit** Expanding to the form $12x^2-xy-y^2-41x+2y-4=0,$ it is a [hyperbola](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conic_section#Discriminant) since $B^2-4AC=(-1)^2-4\cdot 12\cdot (-1)=37>0.$

To get the canonical form it is convenient to find the center. In maxima CAS: `solve([diff(12*x^2-x*y-y^2-41*x+2*y-4,x),diff(12*x^2-x*y-y^2-41*x+2*y-4,y)],[x,y]);`. It is $(\frac{12}{7},\frac17).$ (To check expand $12(x-12/7)^2-(x-12/7)(y-1/7)-(y-1/7)^2-39=0$).

Now rotate by $\theta=\frac{\arctan{\frac1{13}}}{2}$ since $\tan{2\theta}=\frac{B}{C-A}$ with the rotation \begin{pmatrix}\cos\theta&\sin\theta\\-\sin\theta&\cos\theta\end{pmatrix} eliminates the $xy$ term.

The eigenvalues of the matrix $\begin{pmatrix}A&B/2\\B/2&C\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}12&-1/2\\-1/2&-1\end{pmatrix}$ reveal the form $\frac{\sqrt{170}+11}{2} x'^2-\frac{\sqrt{170}-11}{2}y'^2=39.$ And the canonical form is $$(\frac{x'}{\frac{2\cdot 39}{\sqrt{170}+11}})^2-(\frac{y'}{\frac{2\cdot 39}{\sqrt{170}-11}})^2=1.$$

Comment: Are you sure? it doesn`t seem like the general equation of the hyperbola

Comment: It expands to $12x^2-xy-y^2-41x+2y-4=0.$ If you want I can give the canonical form of it.

Comment: if you don`t mind , I would like that